# How can I call a Perl script from PHP?

Tags: php, perl

I am interested in knowing the ways we can call/run Perl scripts in PHP.

Comment: Related: [How can I call Perl from my PHP page on apache?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/827302), [Calling Java (or python or perl) from a PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/299913), [How to run perl script with a few arguments from php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2908274), [How can I include the output of a Perl script into a PHP page?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1043230)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I include the output of a Perl script into a PHP page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043230/how-can-i-include-the-output-of-a-perl-script-into-a-php-page)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030736/how-can-i-use-perl-libraries-from-php

Answer (score 15):

You can use a simple Php Perl extension within the Php code. This will allow you to execute code and Perl variables,functions and instantiate objects.

```
$perl = new Perl();
$perl->require("test1.pl");
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  I have made small formatting changes to your question to use the code highlighting features of SO.

Comment: Is there any way to download .dll file?

Comment: Does this work even without the `perl` binary installed?

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of

- [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)
- [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
- [backtick operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Answer (score 2):

Just like any other executable.

But avoid it, it's very inefficient.  What do you want to achieve by doing it?

Comment: I was trying to use perl for accessing system resources like webcam, then call that script in my existing php application.

Comment: @awake416 Whose webcam? If there is a webcam attached to the server and you can access it using Perl, then it should not be difficult to access it in PHP as well.

Comment: @Sinan how can i access in php

Comment: @awake416 I don't know. Just like I do not know how you are accessing it in Perl. All I am saying is, if you can do it in one, you should be able to do it in the other language as well.

Comment: Conversely, you can write your whole website in Perl using mod_perl to avoid the overhead of invoking the Perl interpreter on each call.

Comment: PS: People tell me there are better alternatives to mod_perl to do that nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
system("/your/kewl/script.pl");
```